# iOS ShareKit Cancel button is not working with Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, sharekit

The iOS Sharekit working with previous Xcode but will 4.2 it's not working anymore, When I hit the Cancel button it goes to this routine

Inside the SHK.m

```
  - (void)hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
  {


if (isDismissingView)
return;

if (currentView != nil)
{
    // Dismiss the modal view
    if ([currentView parentViewController] != nil)
    {
        self.isDismissingView = YES;
        [[currentView parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }

    else
        self.currentView = nil;
}
```

}

I stepped the code and it just hit if (isDissmissingView) and it just return.
So, I manually inserted the code

```
   [[currentView parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
```

to the top of the routine but this doesn't do anything.

I also includes some other codes for reference

```
  - (void)showViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
```

{

```
  if (rootViewController == nil)
{
    // Try to find the root view controller programmically

    // Find the top window (that is not an alert view or other window)
    UIWindow *topWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    if (topWindow.windowLevel != UIWindowLevelNormal)
    {
        NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
        for(topWindow in windows)
        {
            if (topWindow.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal)
                break;
        }
    }

    UIView *rootView = [[topWindow subviews] objectAtIndex:0];  
    id nextResponder = [rootView nextResponder];

    if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
        self.rootViewController = nextResponder;

    else
        NSAssert(NO, @"ShareKit: Could not find a root view controller.  You can assign one manually by calling [[SHK currentHelper] setRootViewController:YOURROOTVIEWCONTROLLER].");
}

// Find the top most view controller being displayed (so we can add the modal view to it and not one that is hidden)
UIViewController *topViewController = [self getTopViewController];  
if (topViewController == nil)
    NSAssert(NO, @"ShareKit: There is no view controller to display from");


// If a view is already being shown, hide it, and then try again
if (currentView != nil)
{
    self.pendingView = vc;
    [[currentView parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return;
}

// Wrap the view in a nav controller if not already
if (![vc respondsToSelector:@selector(pushViewController:animated:)])
{
    UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease];

    if ([nav respondsToSelector:@selector(modalPresentationStyle)])
        nav.modalPresentationStyle = [SHK modalPresentationStyle];

    if ([nav respondsToSelector:@selector(modalTransitionStyle)])
        nav.modalTransitionStyle = [SHK modalTransitionStyle];

    nav.navigationBar.barStyle = nav.toolbar.barStyle = [SHK barStyle];

    [topViewController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];            
    self.currentView = nav;
}

// Show the nav controller
else
{       
    if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(modalPresentationStyle)])
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = [SHK modalPresentationStyle];

    if ([vc respondsToSelector:@selector(modalTransitionStyle)])
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = [SHK modalTransitionStyle];

    [topViewController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [(UINavigationController *)vc navigationBar].barStyle = 
    [(UINavigationController *)vc toolbar].barStyle = [SHK barStyle];
    self.currentView = vc;
}

self.pendingView = nil;
```

}

- (void)hideCurrentViewController
  {
  [self hideCurrentViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known error, which showed up on ios5. This has been fixed a long time ago in [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/sharekit/sharekit). If you decide to upgrade, make sure to follow [new install wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) very carefully and literally, since many things have changed comparing to the original sharekit
.